# iOS 10 developer option missing from settings

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios10

The topic says it all. I've just upgraded to `iOS 10.0.1 /iPhone 6s/` & now the Developer option is missing from the Settings.

I've tried some tricks for older versions such as sync the device in iTunes and add it in Xcode /it's already added/ but nothing worked.

Anybody has clues on this ?

I'm running `Xcode 7.3.1` with DeviceSupport added from the beta and the apps run fine on the iOS 10.

Comment: Did you try just running an app on the device? Generally that prompts the developer item to appear. Failing that, rebooting the device?

Comment: Rebooted many times, running apps but still nothing..

Comment: Update: After few weeks of no success yesterday I've wiped and reset my iPhone. Unfortunately this didn't help at all...

Comment: Update: It just showed up after updating iOS from 10.0.2 to 10.1 and Xcode from 8.0 to 8.1 beta

Answer (score 15):

Just install XCode 8 and connect your iPhone to your Mac. That worked for me.

Comment: Just tried this last night. Still with no success... Do I have to successfully run a project from Xcode in order to see the options? This means to recompile the whole project /a big one/ to Swift 2.3 or 3 because it refuses to run on Swift 2

Comment: Did you open "Devices" in Xcode and selected your Device?

Comment: Yes, I can see device logs ect. but that option is still missing from the device Settings...

Comment: Please refrain from making such statements. Your comment is practically useless for the topic. If the solution that the answer suggested worked for me I would have already accepted the answer..

Comment: What are this settings for? Any guidelines?

Comment: I'm on Xcode 8.3.2 with iOS 10.2.1. I had to reboot my phone and then it showed up after connecting to my Mac

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by turning off and on the `Show as run destination` from Xcode.

These are the steps:

1. Connect your device
2. Open Xcode and select Window -> Devices and Simulators
3. Select your device from the devices list
4. Toggle the `Show as run destination`

Answer (score 3):

**Try the following steps**

1. Connect your device with your machine.

   2. Open Xcode -> Window -> Devices
   3. Select your device from the left side pan
   4. Now Click on the “+” icon in the downside.
   5. Select “Add Device”
   6. Now do the steps as per the given instructions.
   7. It will show a window as given below.
      [image]
   8. Done

Answer (score 2):

Guess you've probably got this sorted, but may be useful for someone else...

In addition to opening Xcode 8 and connecting the phone I needed to bring up the devices tab (Shift-Cmd-2) and select the phone from the list. After a bit of messing about to convince Xcode that the phone really was unlocked, the Developer option appeared

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 12.x and better, the following sequence enables "Developer Mode" on the iOS device:

- Device must have a passcode set.
- Plug the device to your laptop.
- Enter DFU mode:
  -- Hold both “Home” + “Power” buttons on your device at the same time for 10 seconds.
  -- Release the “Power” button while keeping the home button pressed, for another 10 seconds.
  -- Release “Home”. The device's screen will be black.
- Leave DFU mode:
  -- Press "power" + "home" until the device reboots.
- In Xcode, go to Devices View . Select the device and tick "Run as destination" (untick + tick if already ticked)
  ==> Developer options will be available in setting after reboot.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 9.2 it's Product->Destination->Device.
Then on iOS 11.21 it's Settings-General->Profiles and Device Management.  A "Developer App" profile will be there for your Apple ID once you've successfully built your project with the build target of your phone, that's where you click on "Trust" "".

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 9 following are the steps:

- Connect your iPhone or iPad to your computer
- Hold the “Home” + “Power” buttons on your iPhone and iPad at the same time for 10 seconds.
- Let go of the “Power” button without releasing the home button. Continue press the “Home” button for another 10 seconds.
- Release “Home”, and your screen should stay completely black. If so, chances are you successfully entered into iPhone DFU Reset.
- Developer options will be available in setting after reboot.